# How to work with ' df.loc ' so that it combines two columns to return ' unique ' values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I ran into a problem when I tried to combine two columns before generating a unique list.

CSV file:

```
country,half,uniqueTournament
Brazil,1st half,Serie A
England,1st half,Championship
Argentina,2nd half,Primera Liga
Brazil,1st half,Serie A
```

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = '@@@@@@@@@@@@@'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

df.loc[(df['half'] == '1st half'), 'country' + ' - ' + 'uniqueTournament'].unique()
```

Expected outcome:

```
Brazil - Serie A
England - Championship
```

Comment: Use `out = (df['country'] + ' - '+ df['uniqueTournament']).unique()`

Comment: Hello friend @enke , thanks for the help but my problem is because I need to work with this filter in relation to some columns, such as the one I put ```(df['half'] == '1st half')```. Well that's my question about how to do it if I need ```df.loc```

Comment: could you give an example where `"half"` is relevant with the expected outcome?

Comment: Sure mate @enke, for example, if ```Argentina,2nd half,Primera Liga``` → ```2nd half``` instead ```1st half```

Comment: I try this way ```(df.loc[(df['half'] == '1st half'), 'country'] + ' - ' + df.loc[(df['half'] == '1st half'), 'uniqueTournament']).unique()``` But it returned the values in a sequence of two on each line and I was a little suspicious, but it's correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df` was like:

```
     country      half uniqueTournament
0     Brazil  1st half          Serie A
1    England  1st half     Championship
2  Argentina  1st half     Primera Liga
3     Brazil  1st half          Serie A
4     Brazil  2nd half          Serie A
```

then you could create a new column, then `groupby` + `agg(list)`:

```
df['new'] = df['country'] + ' - '+ df['uniqueTournament']
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['half','new']).groupby('half')['new'].agg(list).tolist()
```

or you could use `groupby` + `unique`:

```
out = df.groupby('half')['new'].unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['Brazil - Serie A', 'England - Championship', 'Argentina - Primera Liga'],
 ['Brazil - Serie A']]
```